# Server-centric application that can access client-side API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, serverside-javascript, webspeech-api

I'm starting to plan a little project, the application I'm building needs to access the client-side JavaScript APIs to utilize things like the Web Speech API and the Camera API.

I also noted that the application should be able to perform lengthy computations and deliver them as quick as possible, therefore a server-centric application makes sense due to the removal of XHR and ability to improve hardware centrally.

I'm stuck on what route to take as I'm not sure of the best framework/methodology to use for this. Could anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

It comes very much under opinion at this point so take it with a grain of salt. If you are just starting out, take a look at [Meteor JS](http://meteor.com) . If you have already done some development and don't mind writing boilerplate code to acheive more flexibility, look at [Express JS](http://expressjs.com/) + [ReactJS](http://reactjs.com). If extreme performance is your goal then replace Express JS with [gin](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin).